# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol при попытке использования dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, link

Пытаюсь подключить собственную библиотеку к проекту в Visual Studio.
Добавил пути к папкам h и lib файлов в Additional Includes Directories и Additional Library Directories. А так же указал имя конкретного lib файла (он один) в Additional Dependencies.

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
#include <SwiftWindow.h> //Заголовочный файл библиотеки

using namespace swift; //Её пространство имен

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPreviousInst,
LPSTR lpCommandLine, int nCommandShow) {

SwiftWindow window(hInst, lpCommandLine, nCommandShow);
window.createWindow(_T("Test window"), 800, 600);//!Без этой строки компилирует и  
выполняет программу. 

return 0;
}
```

Так же приведу файлы библиотеки 
Заголовочный файл

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

//@Namespace swift
namespace swift {

/*@Class SwiftWindow
*/
class SwiftWindow
{
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    /*@Func SwiftWindow(consructor)
    */
    __declspec(dllexport) SwiftWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, LPSTR lpCommandLine, int nCommandShow);

    __declspec(dllexport) void createWindow(const TCHAR *title, int width, int height);

    __declspec(dllexport) ~SwiftWindow();
private:
    HWND _hMainWnd;

    HINSTANCE _hInst;
    int _nCommandShow;
};

}
```

Файл исходного кода

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SwiftWindow.h"

namespace swift {

__declspec(dllexport)
SwiftWindow::SwiftWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, LPSTR lpCommandLine,
    int nCommandShow) :_hInst(hInst), _nCommandShow(nCommandShow)
{

}

__declspec(dllexport)
void SwiftWindow::createWindow(const TCHAR* title, int width, int height) {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = _hInst;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = _T("swiftApp");
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        throw;//TODO: Ñäåëàòü èñêëþ÷åíèÿ.
    }

    _hMainWnd = CreateWindow(_T("swiftApp"), title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, NULL, NULL, _hInst, NULL);

    if (!_hMainWnd) {
        throw; //TODO: Ñäåëàòü èñêëþ÷åíèÿ.
    }

    ShowWindow(_hMainWnd, _nCommandShow);
    UpdateWindow(_hMainWnd);
}ФФФФ

__declspec(dllexport) SwiftWindow::~SwiftWindow()
{
}

__declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK SwiftWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uInt,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Жду ваших замечаний

Ошибки:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: boolAnalys, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall swift::SwiftWindow::createWindow(char const *,int,int)" (?createWindow@SwiftWindow@swift@@QAEXPBDHH@Z) referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>C:\Users\Георгий\Source\Repos\Lists\boolAnalys\Debug\boolAnalys.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Конкретное сообщение об ошибке вы предлагаете угадывать? 
Возможны разночтения с преобразованием имен, поэтому нужно указать и полные имена всех файлов с исходниками.

Comment: Ошибку добавил в посте, имена файлов библиотеки:
C:\Users\Георгий\Source\Repos\Lists\SwiftGUIdll\SwiftGUIdll\SwiftWindow.h

c:\users\георгий\source\repos\lists\swiftguidll\swiftguidll\swiftwindow.cpp

Comment: А имя файла с main?

Comment: C:\Users\Георгий\Source\Repos\Lists\boolAnalys\boolAnalys\main.cpp

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать так:

В начале header'а:

```
#if COMPILING_SWIFT_DLL
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

и дальше

```
namespace swift {

/*@Class SwiftWindow
*/
class SwiftWindow
{
public:
    DLLEXPORT static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
...
```

И комплировать DLL с ключом препроцессора `COMPIING_SWIFT_DLL`.

Объяснение: в том месте, где вы подключаете вашу DLL, должно быть видно не `__declspec(dllexport)`, а `__declspec(dllimport)`.

---

Расследование в комментариях показало, что у библиотеки и у главной программы были разные настройки `UNICODE` при компиляции. С точки зрения библиотеки, была объявлена функция

```
void SwiftWindow::createWindow(const wchar_t* title, int width, int height)
```

а программа видела в header'е и соответственно ожидала

```
void SwiftWindow::createWindow(const char* title, int width, int height)
```

Comment: Сделал всё, как Вы предложили. Ошибка не исчезла:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall swift::SwiftWindow::createWindow(char const *,int,int)" (__imp_?createWindow@SwiftWindow@swift@@QAEXPBDHH@Z) referenced in function _WinMain@16

Comment: @GeorgePopoff: А вы не забыли подключить .lib?

Comment: В Additional Dependencies SwiftGUI.lib присутствует.
Странно то, что без строчки
window.createWindow(_T("Test window"), 800, 600);
Программу компилирует и выполняет! То есть конструктор работает корректно и линковщик его видит 
SwiftWindow window(hInst, lpCommandLine, nCommandShow);

Comment: @GeorgePopoff: Хм. Странно. А может быть, разные настройки Unicode? Посмотрите `sizeof(TCHAR)` в обоих проектах.

Comment: Ух, действительно, макроконстанты были определена в библиотеке, но не в коде, который её использовал. Из-за этого линковщик и не видел определение:)
Большое спасибо, теперь все компилируется без ошибок.

Comment: @GeorgePopoff: Отлично! Добавлю в ответ.